# How to add a subplot to a plot with control widgets

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, text, widget

I would like to extend solution of the question ["*How to keep some text relative to the line into the plot when the plot changes*"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51266355/how-to-keep-some-text-relative-to-the-line-into-the-plot-when-the-plot-changes?noredirect=1#comment89514937_51266355) with two subplots controlled with a pair of widget sliders.

The code I have tried it makes no errors, but it does not show the Figure nor the controls.

```
from ipywidgets import widgets
from IPython.display import display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib notebook

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots(211)
line1, = ax1.semilogx([],[], label='Multipath')
hline1 = ax1.axhline(y = 0, linewidth=1.2, color='black',ls='--')
text1 = ax1.text(0, 0, "T Threshold",
                verticalalignment='top', horizontalalignment='left',
                transform=ax1.get_yaxis_transform(),
                color='brown', fontsize=10)
ax1.set_xlabel('Separation Distance, r (m)')
ax1.set_ylabel('Received Power, $P_t$ (dBm)')
ax1.grid(True,which="both",ls=":")
ax1.legend()

fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots(212)
line2, = ax2.semilogx([],[], label='Monostatic Link')
hline2 = ax2.axhline(y = 0, linewidth=1.2, color='black',ls='--')
text2 = ax2.text(0, 0, "R Threshold",
                verticalalignment='top', horizontalalignment='left',
                transform=ax2.get_yaxis_transform(),
                color='brown', fontsize=10)
ax2.set_xlabel('Separation Distance, r (m)')
ax2.set_ylabel('Received Power, $P_t$ (dBm)')
ax2.grid(True,which="both",ls=":")
ax2.legend()

def update_plot(h1, h2):
    D = np.arange(0.5, 12.0, 0.0100)
    r = np.sqrt((h1-h2)**2 + D**2)
    freq = 865.7 #freq = 915 MHz
    lmb = 300/freq 
    H = D**2/(D**2+2*h1*h2)
    theta = 4*np.pi*h1*h2/(lmb*D)
    q_e = H**2*(np.sin(theta))**2 + (1 - H*np.cos(theta))**2
    q_e_rcn1 = 1
    P_x_G = 4 # 4 Watt EIRP
    sigma = 1.94
    N_1 = np.random.normal(0,sigma,D.shape)
    rnd = 10**(-N_1/10)
    F = 10
    y = 10*np.log10( 1000*(P_x_G*1.622*((lmb)**2) *0.5*1) / (((4*np.pi*r)**2) *1.2*1*F)*q_e*rnd*q_e_rcn1 )
    line1.set_data(r,y)

    hline1.set_ydata(-18)
    text1.set_position((0.02, -18.5))
    ax1.relim()
    ax1.autoscale_view()
    fig1.canvas.draw_idle()
    ######################################
    rd =np.sqrt((h1-h2)**2 + D**2)
    rd = np.sort(rd)
    P_r=0.8
    G_r=5 # 7dBi
    q_e_rcn2 = 1
    N_2 = np.random.normal(0, sigma*2, D.shape)
    rnd_2 = 10**(-N_2/10)
    F_2 = 126 # 21 dB for K=3dB and P_outage = 0.05
    y = 10*np.log10(  1000*(P_r*(G_r*1.622)**2*(lmb)**4*0.5**2*0.25)/((4*np.pi*rd)**4*1.2**2*1**2*F_2)*
            q_e**2*rnd*rnd_2*q_e_rcn1*q_e_rcn2  )
    line2.set_data(rd,y)
    hline2.set_ydata(-80)
    text2.set_position((0.02, -80.5))
    ax2.relim()
    ax2.autoscale_view()
    fig2.canvas.draw_idle()

r_height = widgets.FloatSlider(min=0.5, max=4, value=0.9, description= 'R_Height:')
t_height = widgets.FloatSlider(min=0.15, max=1.5, value=0.5, description= 'T_Height:')
widgets.interactive(update_plot, h1=r_height, h2=t_height)
```

In the second subplot, there would be a horizontal line at y=-80 with a text that should move in a similar way as the first subplot of the figure.

How could I add the second subplot using the same controls?

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code does produce an error. The problem is that you are creating a figure with 211 (i.e. twohundredeleven) subplots. Those are stored in an array called `ax1` and this array does not have a `.semilogx` method. Hence the error `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'semilogx'`.

So, what you need instead is only two subplots, which you may directly unpack.

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2)
```

The rest is basically adjusting the code for the new situation. It should then look like this:

```
from ipywidgets import widgets
from IPython.display import display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib notebook

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2)
line1, = ax1.semilogx([],[], label='Multipath')
hline1 = ax1.axhline(y = 0, linewidth=1.2, color='black',ls='--')
text1 = ax1.text(0, 0, "T Threshold",
                verticalalignment='top', horizontalalignment='left',
                transform=ax1.get_yaxis_transform(),
                color='brown', fontsize=10)
ax1.set_xlabel('Separation Distance, r (m)')
ax1.set_ylabel('Received Power, $P_t$ (dBm)')
ax1.grid(True,which="both",ls=":")
ax1.legend()

line2, = ax2.semilogx([],[], label='Monostatic Link')
hline2 = ax2.axhline(y = 0, linewidth=1.2, color='black',ls='--')
text2 = ax2.text(0, 0, "R Threshold",
                verticalalignment='top', horizontalalignment='left',
                transform=ax2.get_yaxis_transform(),
                color='brown', fontsize=10)
ax2.set_xlabel('Separation Distance, r (m)')
ax2.set_ylabel('Received Power, $P_t$ (dBm)')
ax2.grid(True,which="both",ls=":")
ax2.legend()

def update_plot(h1, h2):
    D = np.arange(0.5, 12.0, 0.0100)
    r = np.sqrt((h1-h2)**2 + D**2)
    freq = 865.7 #freq = 915 MHz
    lmb = 300/freq 
    H = D**2/(D**2+2*h1*h2)
    theta = 4*np.pi*h1*h2/(lmb*D)
    q_e = H**2*(np.sin(theta))**2 + (1 - H*np.cos(theta))**2
    q_e_rcn1 = 1
    P_x_G = 4 # 4 Watt EIRP
    sigma = 1.94
    N_1 = np.random.normal(0,sigma,D.shape)
    rnd = 10**(-N_1/10)
    F = 10
    y = 10*np.log10( 1000*(P_x_G*1.622*((lmb)**2) *0.5*1) / (((4*np.pi*r)**2) *1.2*1*F)*q_e*rnd*q_e_rcn1 )
    line1.set_data(r,y)

    hline1.set_ydata(-18)
    text1.set_position((0.02, -18.5))
    ax1.relim()
    ax1.autoscale_view()

    ######################################
    rd =np.sqrt((h1-h2)**2 + D**2)
    rd = np.sort(rd)
    P_r=0.8
    G_r=5 # 7dBi
    q_e_rcn2 = 1
    N_2 = np.random.normal(0, sigma*2, D.shape)
    rnd_2 = 10**(-N_2/10)
    F_2 = 126 # 21 dB for K=3dB and P_outage = 0.05
    y = 10*np.log10(  1000*(P_r*(G_r*1.622)**2*(lmb)**4*0.5**2*0.25)/((4*np.pi*rd)**4*1.2**2*1**2*F_2)*
            q_e**2*rnd*rnd_2*q_e_rcn1*q_e_rcn2  )
    line2.set_data(rd,y)
    hline2.set_ydata(-80)
    text2.set_position((0.02, -80.5))
    ax2.relim()
    ax2.autoscale_view()

    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

r_height = widgets.FloatSlider(min=0.5, max=4, value=0.9, description= 'R_Height:')
t_height = widgets.FloatSlider(min=0.15, max=1.5, value=0.5, description= 'T_Height:')
widgets.interactive(update_plot, h1=r_height, h2=t_height)
```

Comment: Thank you. The plot seamlessly updates with the controls. I would like to ask you as a final question how could I convert one of the subplots from semilogx to scatter plot? I have tried to change `semilogx` for `scatter`but give error as scatter is not iterable.

Comment: it says "'PathCollection' object is not iterable" and if I take out the comma after `line2` for example (is scatter is the second subplot) then the error is "AttributeError: 'PathCollection' object has no attribute 'set_data'" and points to line `line2.set_data(rd,y)`.

Comment: That is really a different question.. that for sure has an answer elsewhere, if you google for "matplotlib update scatter".

Comment: You are right. I have searched but found only answer referred to offset in animations with scatter plots.

Comment: See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42722691/python-matplotlib-update-scatter-plot-from-a-function).

Comment: It works. However, if I take semilog x-scale with `ax2.set_xscale('log')` the plot does not work.